# jQuery script is not executing, but they work in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm having issues across the board with getting my scripts to work. They work fine in jsFiddle but when I take them into the site I don't see the script taking effect.

My question is, what is best practice for getting script implemented into a page? Is it frowned upon to copy/paste?

For reference, here is the jsfiddle that works http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TgFvP/15/, and the page I'm not seeing the effect taking place http://www.tailwatersflyfishing.com/sage-fly-rods

I'm super new at this, so I'm sure it's something standard that I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using a very old version of jquery on the site (1.3.2). On jsFiddle it's using the latest of 1.7.1. Try updating jquery and see if that helps. Also, you're missing a curly brace for the document ready portion.

Comment: I'll update jquery and see if it helps

Comment: I updated jquery to 1.7.1 and the entire site would not function

Answer (score 0):

jQuery script should wrapped in

```
$(function() {
...
...
}
```

Because jQuery functions needs to be executed only when the DOM is ready.

Comment: From the page he linked to, you can see he's already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with that code snippet in particular is that you're missing the closing `});` for the `$(document).ready()` block;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('.rod-list').hover(function(){
       $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    }, function() {
       $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    });
// Add }); here!
</script>
```

**However**, an even bigger problem for you is that you're also including PrototypeJS in the page, which overrides `$` itself to be it's own special thing; so even if you fix the `<script>` you'll get a *Cannot call method 'ready' of null* error.

To fix *this* you'll need to use the following;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('document').ready(function($){

    $('.rod-list').hover(function(){
       $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    }, function() {
       $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    });

});
</script>
```

This uses `jQuery()` which hasn't been overridden by Prototype, and so will still work. Inside the ready handler, we then pass a `$` so that *inside* the ready handler, you can use `$` as a handy alias for jQuery **but outside of the ready handler, `$` will be Prototype**.

Comment: Matt, I put your code in to this page http://www.tailwatersflyfishing.com/sage-fly-rods While I now have no more errors, I still don't see any effects taking place

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts aren't working because you're getting errors that are preventing everything from loading fully. You need to open the console so you can see them. The first place I'd start is [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure your markup is clean (currently there are validation issues).

Answer (score 0):

if you run firebug or another developer tool suite you can see you are missing a curly bracket.

you have this on the site...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.rod-list').hover(function() {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    }, function() {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

and what you need is this...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.rod-list').hover(function() {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    }, function() {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the on ready code that you need:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rod-list').hover(function () {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    }, function () {
        $('.rod-list', this).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

It looks like the page may have other errors as well though.

Side note:

```
$(function () {
```

Is a shortcut for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: The code you gave me creates an error and doesn't work. Currently in chrome the error is on line 1 where the doctype is.